# Example code from emgucv throwing exceptions??

Tags: c#, opencv, machine-learning, emgucv

So i'm using emguCV to use the machine learning algorithms from OpenCV. My code is as follows, and when it enters the dtree.Train method it gives me exception (exc1) and if i wait ir gives me and error message (err1).If i try to debug and step into this method if gives me another exception (exc2) and the debugger doesn't advance.
exc1:
A first chance exception of type 'Emgu.CV.Util.CvException' occurred in Emgu.CV.dll

exc2:
Step into: Stepping over non-user code 'Emgu.CV.ML.RTrees.Train'
A first chance exception of type 'Emgu.CV.Util.CvException' occurred in Emgu.CV.dll
Step into: Stepping over non-user code 'MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen'

err1:
The CLR has been unable to transition from COM context 0x795fa8 to COM context 0x796118 . The thread that owns the destination context/apartment is most likely either doing a non pumping wait or processing a very long running operation without pumping Windows messages. This situation generally has a negative performance impact and may even lead to the application becoming non responsive or memory usage accumulating continually over time. To avoid this problem, all single threaded apartment (STA) threads should use pumping wait primitives (such as CoWaitForMultipleHandles) and routinely pump messages during long running operations.

My Code, using this example - http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Mushroom_Poisonous_Prediction_(Decision_Tree)_in_CSharp

```
   public void train()
    {

        Matrix<float> data, response;
       // data = new Matrix<float>(15, 200);
       // response = new Matrix<float>(15, 200);
        Console.WriteLine("reading shroom data");
        ReadMushroomData(out data, out response);

        ///data = new Matrix<float>(1, 5);

        //Use the first 80% of data as training sample
        int trainingSampleCount = (int)(data.Rows * 0.8);

        Matrix<Byte> varType = new Matrix<byte>(data.Cols + 1, 1);
        varType.SetValue((byte)Emgu.CV.ML.MlEnum.VAR_TYPE.CATEGORICAL); //the data is categorical

        Matrix<byte> sampleIdx = new Matrix<byte>(data.Rows, 1);
        using (Matrix<byte> sampleRows = sampleIdx.GetRows(0, trainingSampleCount, 1))
            sampleRows.SetValue(255);

        float[] priors = new float[] { 1, 0.5f };
        GCHandle priorsHandle = GCHandle.Alloc(priors, GCHandleType.Pinned);

        MCvRTParams param = new MCvRTParams();
        param.maxDepth = 8;// max depth
        param.minSampleCount = 10;// min sample count
        param.regressionAccuracy = 0;// regression accuracy: N/A here
        param.useSurrogates = true; //compute surrogate split, no missing data
        param.maxCategories = 15;// max number of categories (use sub-optimal algorithm for larger numbers)
        param.cvFolds = 10;
        //param.use1seRule = true;
        param.truncatePrunedTree = true;
        param.priors = priorsHandle.AddrOfPinnedObject(); // the array of priors


        Console.WriteLine("starting train");
        using (RTrees dtree = new RTrees())
        {

            bool success = dtree.Train(data, 
                Emgu.CV.ML.MlEnum.DATA_LAYOUT_TYPE.ROW_SAMPLE, 
                response, 
                null, 
                sampleIdx, 
                varType, 
                null, 
                param);


            Console.WriteLine("starting tests");

            if (!success) return;
            double trainDataCorrectRatio = 0;
            double testDataCorrectRatio = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < data.Rows; i++)
            {
                using (Matrix<float> sample = data.GetRow(i))
                {
                    double r = dtree.Predict(sample, null);
                    r = Math.Abs(r - response[i, 0]);
                    if (r < 1.0e-5)
                    {
                        if (i < trainingSampleCount)
                            trainDataCorrectRatio++;
                        else
                            testDataCorrectRatio++;
                    }
                }
            }

            trainDataCorrectRatio /= trainingSampleCount;
            testDataCorrectRatio /= (data.Rows - trainingSampleCount);

            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Prediction accuracy for training data :{0}%", trainDataCorrectRatio * 100));
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Prediction accuracy for test data :{0}%", testDataCorrectRatio * 100));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

after a lot of testing and trial and error i found this:
-i debug emgucv with its source code and found a description of the errors (which weren't very helpful)

-i started to see where the errors happened and i commented this line param.priors = priorsHandle.AddrOfPinnedObject(); // the array of priors

-i got the train and test to work, althought it can't predict nothing with RTrees. Even with the mushroom example i tried just to change the Dtrees to Rtrees and i got no results with them too. Maybe i need to tune parameters. Anyway i solve the error on commenting that line.

Answer (score 0):

To make it to work you should simply use `param = MCvRTParams.GetDefaultParameter();` I got it to work with x64 configuration